# How to enable GPU rendering with my Radeon card in Linux?

Tags: opencl

I am currently running Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit on a machine with a Radeon R9 270X GPU.

I've grabbed the latest 64-bit Linux build from [this page](https://builder.blender.org/download/) (currently 2.75-a08f8a4) and I have installed the latest Catalyst drivers directly from AMD's website (currently 15.20.1046-150622a-186193C).

However, no matter what I do, I still don't see an OpenCL option anywhere in Blender's user preferences:

[image]

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Note: I tried setting the `CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1` environment variable but it made no difference.

Comment: Just a small thing to clarify - you do reboot Blender every time after some important changes (it may be not so important though; but still)?

Comment: @MrZak yes, I restarted Blender and rebooted the computer after every change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**AHA!**

So it turns out that I needed the [ocl-icd-opencl-dev [image: Install ocl-icd-opencl-dev]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ocl-icd-opencl-dev) package installed. Once I installed that package...

[image]

\o/